# GPUImageColorBalanceFilter not working

Tags: ios, uiimage, gpuimage, imagefilter

I am using GPUImageColorBalanceFilter as defined in https://github.com/liovch/GPUImage. But the filtered image doesn't appear changed from original image at all on being displayed! The code runs well without errors. What am i doing wrong?

```
CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:beginImage
                                 fromRect:[beginImage extent]];
BOOL preserveLuminosity = NO;
GPUVector3 shadows= (GPUVector3){1,0.0,1};
GPUVector3 midtones = (GPUVector3){-1,-1,0.13};
GPUVector3 highlights = (GPUVector3){0.0,-1,1};
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
GPUImagePicture *pic1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:img1];
GPUImageColorBalanceFilter *filter1 = [[GPUImageColorBalanceFilter alloc] init];
[filter1 setShadows:shadows];
[filter1 setMidtones:midtones];
[filter1 setHighlights:highlights];
[filter1 setPreserveLuminosity:preserveLuminosity];
[pic1 addTarget:filter1];
[pic1 processImage];

UIImage *new= filter1.imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput;
self.imageView.image = new;
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

Note: Since I was already working with bradlarson's GPUImage library, I added GPUImageColorBalanceFilter.h, GPUImageColorBalanceFilter.m, GPUImageOpenGLESContext.h, GPUImageOpenGLESContext.m from https://github.com/liovch/GPUImage to my codebase.

Comment: That's an ancient fork, relatively speaking, and the way that filters operate has changed since then. Simply pulling those filters in to the current code path won't work, you'll need to update them to use the current interfaces. In particular, the accessors will need to be updated to use the current style. See something like the gamma filter for how accessors are supposed to work now.